# Native Flash on mobile platforms?

Tags: iphone, android, flash, native

Does anyone know if Flash will be able to run independent from the browser?

I mean `native apps in Flash`, not just the player in a browser.

The `Symbian OS` can do that, however I have yet to find an article which explicitly states what will become available in the case of the iPhone and the Android platform.

I am not asking about dates, as those are the most fluctuation prone variables.

I am part of a `web/mobile apps development` company which is eager to use flash to make applications even richer in content and user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe announced yesterday to all the people who signed up for notification about Flash CS5 beta that they would not be releasing the beta to the public so that they can accelerate the speed at which they can get it onto retail shelves (my guess here is they want money sooner and to not restrict themselves into license timetables on the beta).

You will be able to compile FLAs into native iPhone applications using Flash CS5.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Adobe announced that they were porting Flash to the Android platform, but I think it's being implemented on a device by device basis.  The HTC Hero supposedly has Flash support, but the Droid does not (it's listed as supporting Flash, but it doesn't).

Though, in both cases, Flash support means either viewing a Flash video or running a Flex app in the browser.  From what I've read, there hasn't been any talk of running a swf as a native application.

[HTC Hero: The first Android device with Flash](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/articles/htchero.html)